# docker compose sharing volumes with mapped to paths

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I have the following yaml

```
version: '2'

services:
  database:
    image: sameersbn/mysql
    container_name: invoiceplane_mysql
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/invoicePlane/mysql:/var/lib/mysql/
    environment:
      - DB_PASS=password
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_NAME=invoiceplane
      - DB_REMOTE_ROOT_NAME=root
      - DB_REMOTE_ROOT_PASS=password
      - DB_REMOTE_ROOT_HOST=172.18.0.%
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    #entrypoint: [/bin/bash, /usr/bin/mysql]
    #entrypoint: mysql -h localhost -uroot -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'172.18.0.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'"
  invoiceplane:
    #image: coelis/invoiceplane
    build: ./invoiceplane
    entrypoint: ['/start.sh']
    ports :
      - "10180:80"
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/invoicePlane/uploads:/var/www/html/uploads
    volumes_from:
      - invoiceplane-wipay
    depends_on:
      - database
      - invoiceplane-wipay
    links:
      - database:mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=172.18.0.2
      - MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  phpmyadmin:
     image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
     ports :
       - "10181:80"
     environment:
       - MYSQL_USERNAME=root
       - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
     links:
       - database:db
     depends_on:
       - database
  invoiceplane-wipay:
    build: ./php
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: -c 'composer install && ./vendor/bin/watcher ./vendor/bin/phpunit ./tests ./src'
    volumes:
        - ~/Documents/Git/wipay_invoiceplane/invoiceplane-wipay:/usr/src/app:rw
```

I'm trying to map the invoiceplane-wipay volume to a the invoiceplane volume that should reside at a path /packages/invoiceplane-wipay

I tried adding to the invoice plane service

```
volumes:
   - invoiceplane-wipay:/package/invoiceplane-wipay
```

I need to add the volume from the **invoiceplane-wipay service** to the path */package/invoiceplane-wipay* on **invoiceplane service**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your yml:

```
  ...
  invoiceplane:
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/invoicePlane/uploads:/var/www/html/uploads
    volumes_from:
      - invoiceplane-wipay
  ...
  invoiceplane-wipay:
    ...
    volumes:
        - ~/Documents/Git/wipay_invoiceplane/invoiceplane-wipay:/usr/src/app:rw
```

This will mount /usr/src/app from the invoiceplane-wipay container to the invoiceplane container with the same path. If you want to mount this at another location, then you can't use `volumes-from`, and I don't recommend `volumes-from` since it's quickly becoming deprecated and you won't find support for this in swarm mode. You would simply include the same volume source in the other section of the yml:

```
  invoiceplane:
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/invoicePlane/uploads:/var/www/html/uploads
      - ~/Documents/Git/wipay_invoiceplane/invoiceplane-wipay:/packages/invoiceplane-wipay
```

Comment: Wow they are deprecating it? thanks for the heads up

Comment: Not sure if it's officially deprecated, but the writing is on the wall. The main use for this went away when named volumes were added.